# DirectShow IBaseFilter EnumPins returns nothing

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

Using GraphEdit, I can add the filter to the editor and use it to render a video. When I create the instance via COM (using DirectShow.NET), the method EnumPins (followed by Next checks) returns no pins.

Is there a reason why GraphEdit would show the pins and I cannot get a reference to the pins via the COM interfaces?

EDIT: Here is the method I am using to get the first available pin (of any type). Nothing is ever returned for this filter, but I can see 4 pins (two in, two out) in graph edit.

```
public static IPin GetPins(IBaseFilter vSource, int iIndex)
{
    IEnumPins pins;
    var ppPins = new IPin[1];
    if (vSource == null)
        return null;
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(vSource.EnumPins(out pins));
    try
    {
        while (pins.Next(1, ppPins, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
        {
            return ppPins[0];
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pins);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Any specific filter? Have you added it to the graph at enumeration time?

Comment: I don't think the name of the filter is relevant, but it is a 3rd part one, "AVerMedia HD XBar C985 Bus 2". I have added the filter to the graph when enumerating pins.

Comment: Filter is not relevant, so you say it happens with any filter? The code looks about right, I can only think of something external making filter disable itself (missing underlying hardware) and expose no pins. Or, another option is that you are enumerating before adding it into the graph.